# How to make parent width fit content when a child has a negative transform translateX?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, daisyui

This is an example snippet showcasing what I'm trying to achieve. *(please make sure to scroll down, as the 2nd example might be hidden by tailwind warning)*

In the 2nd example, as you can see, the parent box width remains the same and doesn't shrink down to fit the content.

I believe absolute positioning is probably the best to achieve the badge position that I want, however, using absolute positioning will have a similar issue of the parent not adjusting to content size.

```css
/*
 * These styles are just a workaround to fix tailwind/daisyui styles
 *   as for some reason daisyui doesn't override tailwind when using CDN.
 */
.img-link {
  padding:0!important;
  border:none!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daisyui@2.14.1/dist/full.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h1 class="mb-2">Original box</h1>
<div class="inline-block bg-rose-400">
  <a class="btn btn-ghost normal-case text-l p-0 border-0 img-link" href="/">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" class="h-full" alt="madlabz - Wild Rift Builds" />
  </a>
  <span class="badge">badge</span>
</div>

<h1 class="mt-6 mb-2">Badge has `tranform: translateX(-50%)`</h1>
<div class="inline-block bg-rose-400">
  <a class="btn btn-ghost normal-case text-l p-0 border-0 img-link" href="/">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" class="h-full" alt="madlabz - Wild Rift Builds" />
  </a>
  <span class="badge -translate-x-1/2 ">badge</span>
</div>

<div style="height:8rem;"><!-- extra space so that content is scrollable and isn't hidden by tailwind warning --></div>
```

Comment: So what you want to be like , example 1 or example 2?